# Common object to get any Controler object in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have few controllers for Login,Home and etc..

In main method I have launched Login UI

I am writing an interface name Controller which has a method called initializeView(String fxmlLoc,Actionevent event,**parameter here is explained bellow**). In a class called initUI, it implements(Controller) and Override initializeView(..) and has the code to load the needed UI and it's controller with previously loaded controller's data (ex - if I load HOME, then code to show home.fxml and load its controller). That's the place where problem occurs.

Let's say I/m loading HOME in a button press event in Login UI. Then in that button press event I instantiate initUI and calls initializeView method. I pass parameters (String fxmlLoc,Actionevent event,this). The reason for passing 'this' is I need some data in LoginController object of login.fxml. But I can't do that. Coz the method initialzeView has parameters (String fxmlLoc,Actionevent event) only in the interface Controller. I need a parameter to catch LoginController object. But let's say I need to load another object of another UI. So how can I give a common object to catch any UI controller object in initializeView method in interface Controller so I can override that method in initUI without any problem?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is very confusing. You should post the code you're currently trying to make work. But it also sounds like you need to look into Interfaces a little more, because I believe that's exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Zephyr I did it by creating a parent class and extending to to the LoginController. So whenever I want to get any controller object as a parameter I user that parent class and get any controller object..